# How to create a sub folder within a sub folder based a cell value An name the new folder with another value

Tags: excel, vba

Ok I have gone though this, Still not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
Sub Dispatch_WO_Folder()
    If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path) & "\" & Range("E10").Value, :=xlQualityStandard,
    MkDir Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DISPATCHED WORK ORDERS\" & Range("B18") \ Range("E10").Value & ""
    End If
End Sub

Sub Dispatch_WO_PDF()
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & " & Range("E10").Value & ", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DISPATCHED WORK ORDERS\" & Range("E10").Value` - Same applies to the line above it - you do not want the `Range` object inside of the quotes like you are trying to do it.

Comment: Ok i have revised it. But i need the Sub folder to be created in which is named that same as B18          Sub Dispatch_WO_Folder()
    If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DISPATCHED WORK ORDERS\" & \Range("B18")\ & "\" & Range("E10").value , vbDirectory) = " & Range("E10").Value & " Then
        MsgBox "Folder already exists!"
    Else
        MkDir Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DISPATCHED WORK ORDERS\" & Range("E10").Value & ""
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Thank you so  much, I am getting closer i think. Now i get a run-429 error ActiveX unable to create object.

Comment: If the error is different now, can you please update your question to show what the code you have is now? Otherwise no one is going to be able to figure it out.

Comment: Hey braX, I have updated it.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("E10").Value, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _` (you have some extra quotes and a `&` that needed to be removed....

Comment: And this `Range(B18)` should be this `Range("B18")`

Comment: thank you again braX. But i am still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

The code below demonstrates how you can build a full file name step by step and check the result at each stage.

```
Sub Dispatch_WO_Folder()
    ' 302

    Dim FldName     As String
    
    ' 1. Create the name you want to search for before starting the search
    ' 2. don't refer to cells by their range names (too cumbersome)
    FldName = Cells(10, "E").Value                      ' actually, it's Cells(10, 5)
    Debug.Print FldName                                 ' check the name
    FldName = Cells(18, "B").Value & "\" & FldName      ' observe how to add the path separator
    Debug.Print FldName                                 ' check the name
    FldName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DISPATCHED WORK ORDERS\" & FldName
    Debug.Print FldName                                 ' check the name
    
    If Dir(FldName) = vbNullString Then MkDir FldName
End Sub
```

If either E10 or B18 are blank the effort will fail. Therefore here is a slightly more elaborate version of the above procedure that avoids such mishap.

```
Sub Dispatch_WO_Folder()
    ' 302

    Dim Tmp         As String
    Dim FldName     As String
    
    ' 1. Create the name you want to search for before starting the search
    ' 2. don't refer to cells by their range names (too cumbersome)
    FldName = Cells(10, "E").Value                          ' actually, it's Cells(10, 5)
    Debug.Print FldName                                     ' check the name
    If Len(FldName) Then
        Tmp = Cells(18, "B").Value
        If Len(Tmp) Then
            FldName = Tmp & "\" & FldName                   ' observe how to add the path separator
            Debug.Print FldName                             ' check the name
            FldName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DISPATCHED WORK ORDERS\" & FldName
            Debug.Print FldName                                 ' check the name
            
            If Dir(FldName) = vbNullString Then MkDir FldName
        Else
            MsgBox "Cell B18 is blank"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Cell E10 is blank"
    End If
End Sub
```

Once you know that your code is creating the folder name correctly you can remove the various visual checks. The same doesn't go for the automated checks, however, because you will want them to remain effective for as long as you use the code.

Comment: thank you very much, However i am still getting the Error time 429 "ActiveX cannot create object" Any suggestions.

Comment: On which line of my code would you receive that message? And what is the value of `FldName` at that moment? Bear in mind that an unsaved workbook doesn't have a path but proper examination of `FldName` would let you discover that immediately. If this is the case here, consider that often bugs appear in tests that never turn up in practice. If using an unsaved workbook is a contingency that you need to guard against, the structure I gave to the code would make it child's play to add an extra safeguard.

Comment: I figured it out. "ThisWoorkBook" needed to replaced with "ActiveWorkBook", Thank you so much.

Comment: So now when i use this code in another module with different cell valves it does not create the folder and gives me a runtime error.

Comment: You already found the pressure point. `ThisWorkbook` defiens the workbook. `ActiveWorkbook` does not. Therefore `ActiveWorkbook` works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. If your code to always work you must determine which workbook is active. This is because your code wants to use that workbook's path. Therefore, you could also get the path by some other means. But all of this is not part of your question. You have not disclosed what you are trying to do.